# web service sample login using eclipse to create web service

Tags: java, web, service

I have below web application.
Objective is to give success or failure message after database connection.
In this application i am having one Login.jsp and loginHelper.java

Please help me. i need this help.

```
I hava a Login.JSP with below code.
-----------------------------------

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="com.test.loginHelper"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%>
 <% 
  String user = request.getParameter("uname");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pwd");
    int stat;
    //String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=acc";  
     loginHelper tc = new loginHelper();
     stat=tc.checkLogin(user,pass);
    if (stat!= -1) {
     %>
   {"status":"success"}   
    <% }else{
    %>
  {"status":"failed"}
 <%} %>

And i have one one Helper class with name loginHelper.java

package com.test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


//import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.ObjectFactory;

public class loginHelper {

    public int checkLogin(String uname,String pass) {
         int status=-1;
          Connection conn = null;
          String dbName = "Test";
          String serverip="localhost";
          String serverport="1433";
          String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverip+":"+serverport+";databaseName="+dbName+"";
          String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
          String databaseUserName = uname;
          String databasePassword = pass;          
              try {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUserName, databasePassword);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             if (conn!=null) {
                 status=1;
              }
             else
             {
                 status=-1;
             }

        return status;
    }
}
```

When i run this in eclipse with tomcat 7 server configuration.
    in tomcat i get 505 error message please help me out.

Comment: which web browser ( with version number ) you using?

Answer (score 0):

There has some issue with spaces in URL. As you have to remove spaces through encode url like below before passing into connection.

```
String  encodedURL=java.net.URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");
//Than pass it connection as below
DriverManager.getConnection(encodedURL, databaseUserName, databasePassword)
```

Comment: I have done by passing direct url without any embedded value in url.

Comment: Thank for your reply